# change item attribute when it change list-items container

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

i have 2 sortable connected list-items and i want to make the item change his attribute when it change the list container (i mean by drag and drop the item from the first list items to the second one)and here is my code:

```
$(".column").sortable({
    connectWith:    $(".column") ,  
    placeholder:    'widget-placeholder',   
    cursor: 'move' ,
    helper: function (evt, ui) {
        return $(ui).clone().appendTo('body').show();
    },  
    dropOnEmpty: true,  
    zIndex: 10
});

$("#column2").droppable({
    out: function( event, ui ) {
        $(ui.item).attr("rel",'0');
    },
    over: function( event, ui ) {
        $(ui.item).attr("rel",'1');
    }
  });
```

Comment: any chance you can set up a jsFiddle?

Comment: thanks RAAD of corse i will do that and when i finish i'll post the link.

Comment: and here is the link : http://jsfiddle.net/younes_barhouni/umGq7/

Comment: Younes - thanks that's great. What exactly is not working for you in the fiddle?

Comment: I want to change the 'rel' attributs of the item when it change the list container.

Comment: Ok, so your "items" seem to consist of an `li` enclosing an `h3`. Which of these do you want to set the `rel` property for? Also, what behaviour do you want if items are dragged back and forth between the lists (or even reordered in the same list)?

Comment: Tanks again RAAD, as i wrot in Fiddle before each culomn1 lits item have a 'rel' attributs value equal to 1, when This item dragged to culomn2 list items the 'rel' value change to 0, and the same operation when item are dragged back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've made a good start, but there are a few things that need correcting, and some issues you may not have realised:

1. Your items are constructed thus:

   ```
   <li id="1" class="item">
        <h3 rel="1">item1</h3>
   </li>
   ```

   so you need to set the `rel` for the `h3` element, but the code in your jsFiddle is:

   ```
   $("#column2").droppable({
     drop: function( event, ui ) {
       $(this).find('.item').attr("rel",'0');
     }
   });
   ```

   so this is finding all the elements under `$(this)` (i.e. the droppable) that have the class `item` - which corresponds to all the `li` elements. You need to use:

   ```
   ui.item.find("h3").attr("rel", "0");
   ```
2. Your sortable in your jsFiddle is:

   ```
   $(".column").sortable({
       connectWith:    $(".column") ,  
       placeholder:    'widget-placeholder',   
       cursor: 'move' ,
       //  utiliser helper-clone pour que le sortable n'est donc pas contenue par un volet 
       helper: function (evt, ui) {
           return $(ui).clone().appendTo('body').show();
       },  
       dropOnEmpty: true,  
       zIndex: 10
   });
   ```

   the helper function isn't needed - you can just use `helper: "clone"`. I have added `forcePlaceholderSize: true` to my solution, because it provides useful feedback to the user in showing where the droppable is going to be dropped. If ordering is not critical, you can remove it.
3. There is a problem with using `droppable.drop` and `droppable.out` - they do not capture events for droppables that are dropped onto the start or the end of a list (I suspect this is because the droppable has to be dropped ***into*** the list to trigger the events, and if you drop it at the start/end of the list, it's effectively a new position and is not *within* the list).
   So, we can use `sortable` instead:

   ```
   $(".column").sortable({
       connectWith: $(".column"),
       placeholder: "widget-placeholder",
       forcePlaceholderSize: true,
       cursor: "move",
       helper: "clone",
       dropOnEmpty: true,
       zIndex: 10
   });

   $("#column2").on("sortreceive", function (event, ui) {
       ui.item.find("h3").attr("rel", "0");
   });

   $("#column2").on("sortremove", function (event, ui) {
       ui.item.find("h3").attr("rel", "1");
   });
   ```

See my [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/raad/ZzDV9/3/) for a working solution.

Comment: Works Great, thank you very much RAAD for your explanations it helps me a lot, and good day from paris.